# Pacote .TAR AutoInstalavel Linux

Tags: linux, shell-script, gzip

Estou seguindo este procedimento para criar um arquivo `compactado` `autoexecutável` mas não estou tendo êxito, falta alguma coisa?

1. Compacto os arquivos para `pacote.tar.gz`
2. Crio arquivo `pacote.sh` com o seguinte conteúdo:

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
skip=4
tail +$skip $0 1 | tar -xzf - -C /
exit
```

3. Concateno com `cat pacote.tar.gz >> pacote.sh`

Para testar, executo:

```
bash pacote.sh
```

E recebo o seguinte erro:

> > tail: não foi possível abrir “+4” para leitura: Arquivo ou diretório não encontrado tail: não foi possível abrir “1” para leitura: Arquivo
> >     ou diretório não encontrado
>
> gzip: stdin: not in gzip format tar: Child returned status 1 tar:
>   Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Comment: Não seria porque faltou um `|` entre os comandos? `tail ... | tar ...`

Comment: Vou testar hkotsubo

Comment: @hkotsubo o erro agora é outro, editei na pergunta

Comment: Se não me engano, o comando deve ser `tail -n +$skip $0`. Somente `+4` não funciona e ele acha que é um nome de arquivo, e não entendi o que esse `1` está fazendo aí (ele também acha que é um arquivo). Mas não sei se é uma boa basear-se apenas na quantidade de linhas a serem puladas, talvez uma marcação (uma string qualquer indicando onde começa o conteúdo) seja melhor: https://www.linuxjournal.com/content/add-binary-payload-your-shell-scripts

Comment: Vou testar e dou retorno

Comment: @hkotsubo Funcionou perfeitamente, adicionei o `-n`, o `pipe` retirei o `1` e funcionou, crie uma resposta pra eu votar?

Comment: Resposta adicionada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você está usando `tail +$skip $0 1`, e como o valor de `skip` é `4`, o resultado é `tail +4 $0 1`.

Dessa forma, ele acha que `+4` e `1` são nomes de arquivo, daí os erros *"não foi possível abrir “+4” para leitura"* e *"não foi possível abrir “1” para leitura"*.

O certo é usar a opção `-n` para que ele pule as linhas. E remova o `1` também, que parece estar "sobrando" aí:

```
tail -n +$skip $0
```

Outro detalhe é que a saída do comando `tail` deve ser passada como entrada para o comando seguinte (`tar`), e isso é feito através do *pipe* (`|`):

```
tail -n +$skip $0 | tar ...
```

---

De qualquer forma, não sei se é uma boa basear-se apenas na quantidade de linhas a serem puladas (pois se o script for alterado, a quantidade de linhas a serem puladas também muda, e aí você vai ter que ficar mudando o script toda hora).

Talvez uma marcação (uma string qualquer indicando onde começa o conteúdo) seja melhor. Veja um exemplo [neste artigo](http://linuxjournal.com/content/add-binary-payload-your-shell-scripts).